# How to have a union in subquery MySQL Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to perform a subquery in Laravel to get some relevant user data, but the data may be in one of two tables. I have a table for `test_activity` and `live_activity` which both have a `created_at` column. My goal is to get the oldest record from a combination of the data from the two tables.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER, 
  first_name TEXT,
  last_name TEXT
 );

INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES (1, 'Craig', 'Smith'), (2, 'Bill', 'Nye'), (3, 'Bloop', 'Blop');

CREATE TABLE test_activity (
  id INTEGER,
  user_id INTEGER,
  created_at DATE
 );

INSERT INTO test_activity (id, user_id, created_at)
VALUES (1, 1, '2019-04-29'), (2, 2, '2019-03-28'), (3, 3, '2019-04-28');

 CREATE TABLE live_activity (
  id INTEGER,
  user_id INTEGER,
  created_at DATE
 );

INSERT INTO live_activity (id, user_id, created_at)
VALUES (1, 1, '2019-04-27'), (2, 2, '2019-03-29'), (3, 3, '2019-04-27');
```

Here is how I am trying the query with Laravel:

```
$firstActivity = TestActivity::select('created_at')
            ->whereColumn('user_id', 'id');

$firstActivity = LiveActivity::select('created_at')
            ->whereColumn('user_id', 'id')
            ->union($firstActivity)
            ->limit(1)
            ->getQuery();

$users = Users::select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
        ->whereIn('id', $arrayOfIds)
        ->selectSub($firstActivity, 'start_date')
        ->paginate(25);
```

Here is the query as it's being executed and throwing an error:

```
select 
`id`, 
`first_name`, 
`last_name`, 
    ((select `created_at` 
    from `live_activity` 
    where `user_id` = `id`) 
    union 
    (select `created_at` 
    from `test_activity` 
    where `user_id` = `id`
    limit 1) as `start_date` 
from `users` 
where `id` in (....) 
limit 25 
offset 0)
```

The error I get is this

```
Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union
```

How can I make this work? And, is there a better, more efficient way to perform this kind of query with Laravel? Thank you.

UPDATE: 
I've provided sample data for anyone willing to help. Here is the query I am now trying to run:

```
select 
id,
first_name,
last_name,
(select created_at 
from test_activity
where user_id = users.id
union 
select created_at
from live_activity
where user_id = users.id
order by created_at asc
limit 1) as start_date
from users;
```

How can I convert this to eloquent?

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff for now, and instead start with a working query.

Comment: Incidentally, LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry How can I get the union working in the select? I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with that query.

Comment: @Strawberry When I do this I just get the same `start_date` for each user. I modified my local query as well and am now getting the same thing. How do I make it so the where clause in the sub query is utilizing the id of the exact row the rest of the data is tied to?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the corresponding desired result

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases, joins are faster than sub-queries. I recommend working with sql, and testing what is faster before writing it in Laravel, since you aren't using the ORM anyway, and then just rewrite the best query using the query building language.

The join approach would join all three columns, using join where MAX(created_at) on both the testactivity and liveactivity and then using select GREATEST(test_Created_at, live_create_at) as start_date

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how something like that would look with the `MAX`. I think that also might be the opposite of what I am trying. Here is a query I wrote for the test data `select 
users.id,
first_name,
last_name,
LEAST(test_activity.created_at, live_activity.created_at) as start_date
from users
join test_activity on users.id = test_activity.user_id
join live_activity on users.id = live_activity.user_id;` but when I perform this with my live data, I get multiple instances for each user

Comment: yes true. you need to join with a select from the other tables, like join (select max(created_at), user_id from test_activity) using user_id\

Comment: can you give me an idea of what that would look like? I get that the join is possibly more efficient, but I don't get how I am only getting one value from that join. And the query above seems to work if I add `distinct`, but I also need to get the greatest `created_at` from both tables for each user as the `last_activity`, and that seems to break the query and not restrict to distinct user ids